# Using pymongo to connect to MongoDB hosted on AWS

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, raspberry-pi3

Is it possible to connect to mongodb hosted on AWS EC2 instance using pymongo without having mongodb installed locally on the pi?

I am using a raspberry Pi 3 B, and while it has a 64 bit processor and mongodb operates at 64 bit the OS is 32 bit.

Comment: Yes, the drivers work independently of any MongoDB installation.

Comment: Thanks for your help @tfogo